# Magento API, customer.info

Tags: magento

With the Magento SOAP API I can retrieve customer information.

From:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/customer/customer.info.html

A 'customerCustomerEntity' has the following:

```
Type    Name        Description 
int     store_id    Store ID
```

My question:

What is a customer's store_id? Is it the store where he originally signed up or sth. else?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, when you create a new customer in the magento admin you will notice there's a field "Associate to website".

This is so you can have users associated with separate websites on the same installation and keep them separate.

You could have a pet store, and an electronics store for example, and you would like to know which customers registered through which website, this will allow you to target them better for newsletters etc.